# sql puzzle sql server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a small puzzle for myself.
PK is combination of lineNr and typeNr
i want to make a selection where all is_adres is N and the same for all linenrs, the same goes for is_postaddres. And I want the result in one view.

this is wat i want as end result

```
typenr,is_Adres ,is_postaddres 
10, null , 'N'
11, 'N', null
13, 'N', 'N'
```

create table script + testdata

```
CREATE TABLE lineAdres 
( 
 lineNr int,
 typeNr int, 
 is_Adres char(1),
 is_postaddres char(1)
);

INSERT INTO lineAdres VALUES
(1, 10,'J','N'),
(1, 11,'N','J'),
(1, 12,'N','J'),
(1, 13,'N','N'),
(2, 10,'J','N'),
(2, 11,'N','J'),
(2, 12,'J','N'),
(2, 13,'N','N');
```

I want to join this 2 views in  one.. but how, and i got a feeling it could be more efficient!

```
select typenr, is_adres 
from lineAdres
where is_adres = 'N'
group by typenr, is_adres
having count(*) = 2

select typenr, is_postaddres 
from lineAdres
where is_postaddres = 'N'
group by typenr, is_postaddres
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

To join the two result use a CTE and a full join to combine the data.

```
WITH IsAddress AS(
select typenr, is_adres 
from lineAdres
where is_adres = 'N'
group by typenr, is_adres
having count(*) = 2),


IsPostAddress AS (select typenr, is_postaddres 
from lineAdres
where is_postaddres = 'N'
group by typenr, is_postaddres
having count(*) = 2)

SELECT 
       COALESCE(IsAddress.typenr,IsPostAddress.typenr) typenr,
       IsAddress.IsAddress,
       IsPostAdress.is_postaddres
FROM
       IsAddress
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       IsPostAdress
            ON
            IsAddress.typenr = IsPostAdress.typenr
```

Comment: alas it is not so simple , is_adres  and is_postaddres  are  two different columns, i want to output three columns, not two

Comment: Understood. I think it would best be accomplished using a CTE. I've edited the answer to show how.

Comment: No CTEs in SQL Server 2000...use a derived table or some other structure.

Comment: why not use simply union all to combine your query ?you can easily adjust extra COLUMN USING NULL .